# Most effective way of hashing passwords

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

I want to hash the passwords of the users.

I will use a salt.

In the past, I have used md5 but clearly, this is a very outdated way of hashing passwords now.

Is sha256 or sha512 better for effectiveness, not speed.

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of answers on this site, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords might interest you.

Comment: Just to mention: Using slower algorithms also makes it harder for attackers to brute force the hashes. Usually the difference negligible when just hashing single passwords, but attackers must hash thousands of them. What I want to say: Here (exceptional) slower is better ;)

Comment: As KingCrunch said you need the calculation of your hashes to be expensive. Hashing password's is a difficult task to achieve correctly and you should use `a portable public domain password hashing framework` => http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: This ain't a damn duplicate. The only related posts you guys link to are 2.5 years old. Things have changed.

Comment: @seriousdev: How exactly have they changed? Moore's law still holds, md5 is significantly broken, sha512 isn't, and neither is bcrypt (the work factor went up by 1.something as expected). Meanwhile, people are merrily storing passwords in plaintext. I see no significant change, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Define "effectiveness". Obviously, sha512 is more secure, slower and less disk space-efficient than sha256.

Comment: Indeed. But to quote Bruce Schneier, "there's a plenty of fast, insecure algorithms". Slow doesn't have to mean bad, see bcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

for hashing using a salt I recommend the [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) method (implemented in PHP’s [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/hash-hmac))